# extract xml from image column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I have some xml documents stored as an image data type in a sql server 2000 table.  How can I extract the data back to xml and save to a file, or at least see the xml contents in the query window, using just the sql tools?

Comment: Image type?  Why didn't you save them as text?

Comment: Because the database also stores binary data in some cases.  Currently I am only interested in the records that have xml data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959253/converting-sql-server-varbinary-data-into-string-c)

Essentially you want to extract text from varbinary.

Comment: that requires client software to be built.  No way to do it with a query?