# Store and retrieve rtf character codes into sql database

Tags: c#, sql, database, rtf

how can I retrieve the character codes when datatype is varbinary. It only gave the "System.Byte[]" string. Here is my code:

```
    public String getTextText(string name)
    {
        DataTable myData = new DataTable();
        SQLiteCommand cmd;
        SQLiteDataAdapter adptr = new SQLiteDataAdapter(); ;
        SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=database.db;Version=3;New=False;Compress=True;");
        con.Open();
        cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        string sql = "SELECT * FROM parent where name ='" + name + "' ";
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        adptr.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adptr.Fill(myData);
        con.Close();
        return myData.Rows[0][1].ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As explained here: [Varbinary to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959253/converting-sql-server-varbinary-data-into-string-c-sharp)

It depends on how you inserted it into the database in the first place:

```
// if the original encoding was ASCII
 return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myData.Rows[0][1]);

 // if the original encoding was UTF-8
 return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(myData.Rows[0][1]);

 // if the original encoding was UTF-16
 return Encoding.Unicode.GetString(myData.Rows[0][1]);
```

Comment: I insert the rtf character codes in the database with varchar type. Is it really saved in the database as those characters of rtf?

Comment: Is the data in the database varchar?

Comment: can you help with this? I actually retrieved the string not the characters of a rich text format